# simple php Template engine

Tags: php, templates

i friends i am working on simple php template engine here is some code can someboady help me to add files including function
like %include.sidebar.html%  and loop functions so i can run loops  or tell me some other simple php template engine

```
<?

class Template {

private $template, $vars;


public function SetTemplete($tempname) {
    $templatePathAndName  = $tempname;
    if(file_exists($templatePathAndName))
        $this->template = file_get_contents($templatePathAndName);
    else
        die("Template not found... aborting...");
}

public function setVar($var, $content) {
    $this->vars[$var] = $content;
}


public function replaceAll() {
  foreach($this->vars as $var => $content) {
    $this->template = str_replace("{" . strtoupper($var). "}", $content, $this->template);
  }
}

public function publish() {
    $this->replaceAll();
    echo $this->template;
}

public function includeFile(){
  foreach($this->vars as $var => $content) {
    $this->template = str_replace("<-" . strtoupper($var). "->", 
                                  file_get_contents($content), 
                                  $this->template);
  }
}

$tpl = new Template;
$tpl->SetTemplete(base_path."home.html");
$tpl->setVar("SITE_NAME", "Simple Template Class2");
$tpl->publish();

?>
///home.html 
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        {SITE_NAME}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), but php itself is a templating language. Why replace it?

Comment: Interesting read: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php and http://fabien.potencier.org/article/35/templating-engines-in-php-follow-up

Answer (score 1):

[TinyButStrong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/) is ar rather good but still small engine.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't take the time to explain the decision for your choice and show how this answers the question (although I'm not clear what is being asked really). Do this and I'll review my vote.

Answer (score 0):

While slightly less lightweight, [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) is a powerful template engine with extremely simple syntax.

Answer (score 0):

idea, not really formated for your class:

```
<?php
    $glob1 = glob("templates/$template/*");
    for($1=0;$i<=count($glob1)-1;$i++) {
        $file = $glob1[$i];
        $file = str_replace('templates/', '', $file);
        $template = str_replace('%include.$file%', (include("templates/$file")), $template();
    }
?>
```

really hope that helps.